# How Can I Do LIMIT 1, 2 In WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using Wp_Query method and I want to learn is there any parameter to limit my query.
I try to use LIMIT 1,2 in WP_Query.
Thanks for advance!

```
$args = array(
'post_type'     => 'post',
'post_status'   => 'publish',
'orderby' => 'ID',
'order'   => 'DESC',
'meta_query'    => array(
                        array(
                            'key'     => 'featured',
                            'value'   => 'evet',
                            'compare' => '='
                        )
                    )
);

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use **posts_per_page** and **offset** args for `WP_Query()` like:-

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'offset' => 3 ) );
```

for more :- http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters

you are asking for LIMIT 1,2 (means offset,count(how many rows)) so

```
posts_per_page = count
offset = offset
```